# Retrieve second column from List

Tags: c#

I currently have a class to retrieve records from a sql database and put them into a list.
The record have multiple columns and i need to insert the data from the second column from all records into a combobox.

How is this achieved as im unable to find anything about it.

Processor Class:

```
namespace RegForm
{
    public class ClientProcessor
    {
        public List<Client> ClientList = new List<Client>();


        public ClientProcessor()
        {
        }

        public void LoadClients()
        {
            string sqlc = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlconn"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sqlc);

            if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                conn.Open();
            }

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Clients ORDER BY CID", conn);
            try
            {
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                ClientList = new List<Client>();

                if (dr.HasRows)
                {

                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        Client newClient = new Client();
                        newClient.ID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["CID"]);
                        newClient.CNAME= dr["CNAME"].ToString();

                        ClientList.Add(newClient);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception EX)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(EX.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(EX.InnerException);
            }

            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @SaiKalyanAkshinthala - Telling people to google it is not constructive. We don't do that here.

Comment: @Oded, actually this type of question is asked many times in SO. So, I told like that..

Comment: I currently have a class which retrieves a client and returns it as an object into a list. The list contains ID and Name. I need to retrieve the second value from the object. Im able to retrieve the object but unable to display only name for example.

Comment: @SaiKalyanAkshinthala - You said to google it. You didn't say - this has been asked before here, please search the site. Nor did you provide links to duplicate questions.

Comment: You can use LINQ to do this. I have provided a sample code for it. I guess it will work for you.

Comment: Could you show us the code you already have? E.g. how does the list you have look like? And what GUI library are you using (Winforms, WPF, ASP.NET)?

Comment: Edit Question, using Winforms

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data in DataTable, you can do something like:

```
DataTable dt;
List <T> lst = new List<T>();  //replace T with your column type
foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
{
           lst.Add(r[1]); //insert to list
           combobox.Iteam.add(r[1]); //insert to combox 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
class MyData
{
     public string Id{get;set;}
     public string Name{get;set;}
     //Other properties
}
```

Inside bind function

```
public void BindData(List<MyData> list)
{
     //Assuming list is not null
     var dataFromSecondColumn = list.Select(l=>l.Name).ToList();
     //Reset of your code.  
     comboBox1.DataSource = dataFromSecondColumn;
}
```